# Weak law of large numbers - how to use it for Poisson varaibles?

Tags: probability

Let $X\tilde{} Poiss(2)$.  What can we conclude from *Weak law large nubmers*?

I tried to understand this law, but I didn't managed to. Can anyone show me, how does it work in this example ?

Comment: What does the weak law of large numbers say?  What is the expectation of a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=2$?

Comment: I know that $EX=VarX=2$.  The problem is that I would like to understand what tell this theorem using this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weak law of large numbers says that if $M_N=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}{N}$ where $X_i$ are independent identically distributed random variables with mean $m$ then $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(|M_N-m| \geq \epsilon)=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Expanding definitions and plugging in your situation, this means that $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(|M_N - 2| \geq \epsilon) = 0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. When you expand definitions out, you find that there exists a function $N(\epsilon,\delta)$ such that if you average $N(\epsilon,\delta)$ iid copies of $X$ then the result is within $\epsilon$ of $2$ with probability at least $1-\delta$.

One can estimate what $N$ is by using Markov's inequality, if the distribution in question has finite variance. In your case the variance of the sample mean is $\frac{2}{N}$ so you have

$$P(|M_N-2| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{2}{N \epsilon^2}$$

which you can see goes to zero as $N \to \infty$. WLLN still holds without finite variance, however. Also, this bound turns out to be very inaccurate when $N$ is very large; in this case the central limit theorem gives the "sharp" asymptotic, which precisely speaking says that this probability behaves like $e^{-N \epsilon^2}$. Thus, when $N \gg 1/\epsilon^2$ the rate of decay here is actually much faster than $1/N$.

Comment: Tell me please, what does it said in more human :) way.

Comment: @Happyman If you average a large sample from some population, the result is usually close to the population mean. I'm not sure how to state things quantitatively and still "human"-ly.

Comment: It sounds like central limit theorem.

Comment: Not exactly. LLN says essentially "fixed size deviations from the mean vanish in the limit $N \to \infty$". CLT says essentially "$1/\sqrt{N}$ size deviations from the mean do not vanish in the limit $N \to \infty$ but instead they have a universal form". So CLT is really a refinement of LLN.